# Load php file into iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I have a website with 3 links at the top. I want to pull up different files into the iframe when the links are clicked. i got the html file to pull up, but i cannot get the php file to pull up.

```
<a href="records.php" id="records" onClick="changeFrame(this.href); return false">View Records</a>
```

Comment: Without any code examples it's very difficult to help you find the problem

Comment: why not use .live() .click() event and als the .load() function of jquery?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
 <a href="http://bing.com" target="myiframe">bing</a>
 <a href="http://google.com" target="myiframe">google</a>
 <iframe src="#" name="myiframe"></iframe>
```